# Gaussian means model of hypothesis testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons

I have been reading Dobriban *et al* (2015) "Optimal Multiple Testing Under a Gaussian Prior on the Effect Sizes", arXiv:1504.02935 [stat.ME] -- [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1504.02935.pdf) paper, and in section 3.1 it mentions that the approach is 'the Gaussian means model of hypothesis testing' I couldn't find any more information on this approach as a general model elsewhere. It seems as though this paper is only useful for hypothesis testing using a Gaussian distribution, which doesn't fit my purpose, so was hoping to read find a short text book level piece on the Gaussian means model to see if I can figure out a way to use these results for more general distributions

Comment: Gaussian means model Hypothesis testing is a funny expression that the authors made is up :-D and then they explain what they mean by right after the place where they name this model: "We work in the Gaussian means model of hypothesis testing: We observe test statistics ... "

Comment: Yeah, I saw their definition I just didn't know if it was novel to the paper or not. I guess it is